# can't SSH folder into hosting server

Tags: ssh, terminal

I've connected to my hosting company's server via SSH, and have created a subdirectory in the public_html directory. I'd like to copy a website I have developed locally at /Applications/MAMP/my-site-name up into that subdirectory on the server. I've tried: `scp local-directory-containing-site  username@hostname.com:subdirectory`. I keep getting error: No such file or directory. I also tried it with sudo.

I'm guessing this is that my files or directories I want to put on the server can't be found. So how do I find the files/folders on my local machine? I've tried: /Users/my-user-name/Applications/MAMP/... and so on, to no avail. I think it's the local path I need. How do I do this? also, is this the best command to use? And is it the same for files and folders?

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be because you're already logged in via ssh. Try logging out of your current ssh-session, and then use the command as suggested :

```
scp -r /Applications/MAMP/my-site-name username@hostname:/subdirectory
```

Also remember to only use the -r flag if the path really refers to an directory.

Answer (score 0):

For `scp`, you need the *full* path of the remote directory, not just the part relative to the HTTP server's root directory. For instance, if `subdirectory` is in `/var/www`, you would use

```
scp -r local-directory-containing-site \
  username@hostname.com:/var/www/subdirectory
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but the error I get is prefixed by the folder/file name I'm trying to upload:
folder/filename: No such file or directory

Comment: Does `scp -r /Applications/MAMP/my-site-name username@hostname.com:/path/to/subdirectory` work?

Comment: The same error appears after "/Applications/MAMP/directory" with "directory" being the directory where my web site is.